# Difficulties formulating a square matrix algorithm in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, matrix, optimization, time, big-o

I am looking back on some past papers, for my exam, and I have come across a square matrix algorithm question/analysis that I cannot for the life of me approach.

Basically, I am given a N by N matrix (a square matrix basically), and I need to implement a data structure that allows me to increase  the size of the matrix by 1 (row + 1, column + 1) in O(n) time.

After coercing my tutor, I realise the best data structure would be an array of arrays, so so essentially an something like this [ {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9} ] this would denote my matrix, row 1, row 2, row 3

Now I need to be able to expand this matrix by 1 when the increase_size() method is called, I have already tried a naive solution, that is create a new empty array of size 4 sinze our previous matrix has 3 elements, append this array to our matrix_array, and then add a 0 to all the remaining arrays, however this takes O(n^2) time.

I believe there is something here that is related to the rows and columns, when we increase our matrix size we are essentially creating a new row and column, I believe this has something to do with the solution.

I have attached the question below.

[image]

Comment: It's a little frustrating, because I wrote a fairly lengthy answer to this question yesterday, but before I submitted it you deleted the question and now you've reposted it.

Answer (score 1):

Try an array of arrays:

```
M = [ A1, A2, ..., An ]
```

each array `Ax` contains the values `a_{i,j}` if `max(i,j) == x`.

I'll let you do the proofs.

Answer (score 0):

naive solution works in O(n) actually:

1. consider any matrix of size `n * n` implemented as array of arrays (where arrays are dynamic)
2. to reach size `n + 1` we first create a new array of size `n` and append to the end of our matrix, this takes `O(n)` time
3. then for every row in our matrix we append a `0` to the end we have `n + 1` rows and append `1` element each so this too takes `O(n)` time
4. in total runtime is `O(n)`

Comment: Hi, my tutor has not taught us dynamic arrays, so if I use this as an example, i would need to prove the dynamic array data structure.

Comment: Similarly, the tutor stated, i need to keep track of the pointers and not the actual array, if I wish to have a O(n) time complexity

Comment: "We didn't cover dynamic arrays during the lecture, so you'd have to describe the operations you can do on them and show that everything works in the intended time. The latter will be difficult, since dynamic arrays are forced to copy their data once they're completely full in order to be extended and thus you'll most likely not meet the time requirement for expanding the matrix. "

Comment: Well dynamic arrays are O(1) amortized for push_back operations, there's tons of proofs online which are not that difficult

Comment: With this method, increase-size works in amortized O(n) time, but worst-case O(n^2). The answer by OneLyner is guaranteed O(n) time and is more memory-efficient.

Comment: (I guess you can turn this answer into a guaranteed O(n) solution by carefully choosing  how you resize the dynamic arrays so that there's only ever one array line at a time that resizes, but it'll still waste memory compared to the other solution).

Comment: I am unsure if dynamic array would be a way to go because there wouldnt be coninuous memory for the sub arrays, and the question specifies that getting and setting both take o(1) time so linked lists of linked lists wont be the answer either.